# Keras Lambda layer to calculate mean

Tags: python, keras

How can i implement a Lambda layer in Keras that return the mean between two feature vectors?
I tried this:

```
def mean(vects):
    x, y = vects
    return K.sum(K.mean(x+y),axis=1,keepdims=True)
def man_dist_output_shape(shapes):
    shape1, shape2 = shapes
    return (shape1[0], 1)

l = Lambda(mean, output_shape=mean_output_shape)([in1,in2])
```

in1 and in2 are two tensors of feature vectors of dimensions (?,2048) 
The code above works but I don't know if putting K.mean(x+y) is correct. I also tried with

```
return K.sum(K.mean([x,y]),axis=1,keepdims=True)
```

But I have errors.
And I tried `return K.sum((x + y)/2)`, that works too but it is different from the first trial.

Comment: So you want element-wise mean for two tensors right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assuming it's element-wise mean you're looking for, the following will work.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

def mean(vects):
    x, y = vects
    return (x+y)/2.0


def mean_output_shape(shapes):
    shape1, shape2 = shapes
    return shape1

in1 = Input(shape=(2,))
in2 = Input(shape=(2,))
l = Lambda(mean, output_shape=mean_output_shape)([in1,in2])

model = Model(inputs=[in1, in2], outputs=l)
model.summary()
```

And you can test it with

```
import numpy as np
y = model.predict([np.array([[1,1],[1,1]]), np.array([[2,2],[2,2]])])
print(y)
```

Note: Your first code is not correct (assuming you're looking for element-wise mean). Because in this case, you will get the same tensor as the mean. For example, if you have `[1,1]` and `[2,2]` and do `mean(x+y)` it would be `[3,3]` which is not the element-wise mean.